# Android Espresso 2 end phone call

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my app, I have a button that pops up a dialog "Call xxxx-xxxx" Yes / No. After clicking Yes the number shall be called.

This is the test code:

```
@Test
public void testPhoneButton() {
    clickContactTab();

    ViewInteraction phoneButtonInteraction = Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.button_phone));
    phoneButtonInteraction.perform(ViewActions.scrollTo());
    phoneButtonInteraction.perform(ViewActions.click());
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.dialog_phone_title)).inRoot(RootMatchers.isDialog()).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(android.R.id.button2)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Intents.assertNoUnverifiedIntents();
    phoneButtonInteraction.perform(ViewActions.click());
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Intents.intended(Matchers.allOf(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL), IntentMatchers.hasData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tel))));
}
```

Everything works fine, but how can I cancel the phone call after the test?

yogurtearls [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589805/4243464) works for me, thanks:

```
@Test
public void testPhoneButton() {
    clickContactTab();

    ViewInteraction phoneButtonInteraction = Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.button_phone));
    phoneButtonInteraction.perform(ViewActions.scrollTo());
    phoneButtonInteraction.perform(ViewActions.click());
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withText(R.string.dialog_phone_title)).inRoot(RootMatchers.isDialog()).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(android.R.id.button2)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Intents.assertNoUnverifiedIntents();

    phoneButtonInteraction.perform(ViewActions.click());
    Intent stubIntent = new Intent();
    Instrumentation.ActivityResult stubResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, stubIntent);
    Intents.intending(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL)).respondWith(stubResult);
    Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Intents.intended(Matchers.allOf(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL), IntentMatchers.hasData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tel))));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Intent stubbing](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/#intent-stubbing).
You can avoid actually bringing up the dialer, and instead check that the right intent was sent.

Before you click the yes button, call intendING .